# Is there a function for "flattening out" and setting to 0 an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For example if I have some complicated expression (all variables are positive integers) but I want to multiply everything out so there are no denominators and then rearrange so that it is equal to 0, is there a flattening function for this?

To provide an example:

$$x/y + x/y^2 + x/y^3 + x/y^4 = 4/x$$

I want to force it into form

$$x^2y^3 + x^2y^2 + x^2y + x^2 - 4y^4 = 0$$

Comment: If you supply an example and your attempt to work it through, you will likely receive more assistance.

Comment: @zentient Added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqn = x/y + x/y^2 + x/y^3 + x/y^4 == 4/x;

Numerator[Together[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract]] == 0
```

> `x^2+x^2 y+x^2 y^2+x^2 y^3-4 y^4==0`

```
%// TeXForm
```

> $x^2 y^3+x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2-4 y^4=0$

Or,

```
flttnF = Numerator[Together[# /. Equal -> Subtract]] == 0 &;
flttnF@eqn
(* same result *)
```

Comment: By the way I see that you've surpassed Szabolcs on the boards and it looks like belisarius is next.  It seems I may have a successor. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, may be in a few months --  and that assuming belisarius,  Szabolcs, Leonid or rm-rf  will stay on vacation mode  in the meantime -:)

Comment: It's good that you're ready to step up in case a brick falls on my head or something. ;^)

Comment: Lord forbid Mr.W.

Answer (score 0):

```
flattenEqn[eqn_Equal] := Module[
  {factor = Times @@ Denominator /@ (eqn // Together), eqn2},
  eqn2 = factor*# & /@ eqn;
  eqn2[[1]] - eqn2[[-1]] == 0 // Expand]

eqn = x/y + x/y^2 + x/y^3 + x/y^4 == 4/x;

flattenEqn[eqn]
```

> x^2 + x^2*y + x^2*y^2 + x^2*y^3 - 4*y^4 == 0

```
Collect[#, x] & /@ %
```

> -4*y^4 + x^2*(1 + y + y^2 + y^3) == 0